# c++ string concatenation from vector

Tags: c++

I use this code:

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
        if (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe.get()) != nullptr)
            result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}
```

When i want concatenate string from lines array and "hello"

```
std::vector<std::string> lines = split(exec("wmic path win32_baseboard get SerialNumber"), '\n');
std::ostringstream stringStream;
stringStream << lines[1];
stringStream << "hello";
std::cout << stringStream.str() << endl;
```

Then i got output like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHYmF.png)
So word "hello" inserts to start, and replaces my SerialNumber output
But output must be "%SerialNumber%hello"
What i do wrong? :)

Comment: I bet your serial number ends with a `\r`.

Comment: @tkausl Yes that's it! I even couldn't think about it. I just removed `\r` from string, and now it okay. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

As [tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl) mentioned, in Windows the end of string is a combination of CR LF symbols (\r\n) instead of simple Linux-style LF (\n).

See the [console output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuz0Z.png).